# How to sum value of all Key in Redis

Tags: string, redis, sum

In Redis DB, I have many key in String type to save downloads time within a application,
example:

```
   Key            value
20131028:1         100
20131028:2         15
20131028:3         10
..........
```

I want to sum all value of all key by redis command.

Answer (score 17):

Redis is not designed to do this kind of things. You will better served by a RDBMS, MongoDB, or something like ElasticSearch.

Still, if you need to do it (to be launched from a shell):

```
$ redis-cli keys '20131028:*' | awk '{print "get "$1}' | redis-cli | awk '{x+=$1} END { print x }'
```

An other way to do it is to use a Lua server-side script:

```
$ redis-cli eval "local keys = redis.call('keys',KEYS[1]) ; local sum=0 ; for _,k in ipairs(keys) do sum = sum + redis.call('get',k) end ; return sum" 1 '20131028:*'
```

In both cases, performance will suck if you have many keys in the Redis instance, and the instance will be blocked for all connections while the keys are scanned.

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles upon this answer, another good option (if you can) is to add your values in a separate key as they are stored with [INCRBY](https://redis.io/commands/incrby). Then, just get the value previously calculated.

Answer (score 5):

Available since Redis v2.6 is the most awesome ability to execute Lua scripts on the Redis server.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> EVAL "local sum = 0 local i=1 local a1 = redis.call('hvals','Key') while(a1[i]) do sum=sum+a1[i] i=i+1 end return sum" 0
```

> An important note is that Redis server-side lua scripts blocks EVERYTHING, which can be a dealbreaker in most cases. Source: [stackoverflow.com/a/30896608/2440](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30896608/2440)

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to to use mget and fetch all keys with one command instead of issueing one command for each key. that way you get all results with only one call to redis and just have to sum them up. of course this only works if you know the keys beforehand ...

Answer (score 0):

Use redis lua:

```
eval "local s = 0 for _,v in ipairs(redis.call('hvals', KEYS[1])) do s = s + v end return s" 1 Key
```

Could save the script with `script load`, then reuse the script with `evalsha` for any hash key.